# XSLT Group Sum does not display results

Tags: xslt, sharepoint-2010, dataview

I've created a dataview in sharepoint 2010 designer, and use XSLT to display results that are not included by default. I have a field that is calculated and the result can be a negative or a positive number. Detail fields are displayed without problem, but when I try to display the sum of them, in some cases it is displayed correctly and others it doesn't display anything.

From what I've understood, it doesn't display the result of the sum whenever a negative number is less than one thousand negative.

Example: *-1,641*, 296, -613, 0, 1032, 155  -> no result is displayed

Example: 0, -15, -348, -640 -> displays -1003 correctly

I'm using this xslt to display the number

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum($nodeset/@Deviation_x0020_EFC_x0020_vs_x00),'####,##0;(####,##0)')" />
```

If I skip the format-number and just use:

```
<xsl:value-of select="sum($nodeset/@Deviation_x0020_EFC_x0020_vs_x00)" />
```

it will display NaN instead of a blank

There is certainly an issue with the thousand negative numbers, because I've tried to put a format to a number when it is negative and it will work with -603 or -10 but not with -1,640

Comment: It's difficult to help you if you haven't shown us any of the actual XSLT you're trying to use, and if possible, a sampling of the source data.

Comment: It's probably because `1,641` isn't a number. It's a string.